# React update nested object state

Tags: reactjs, use-state

In one of my react project, I have initial state as follow:

```
 const initialValues = {
    en: {
      notificationTitle: "",
      notificationSubTitle: "",
    },
    hi: {
      notificationTitle: "",
      notificationSubTitle: "",
    },
    webUrl: "",
  };

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState(initialValues);
```

I'm passing this state as a props to child components which I'm using them as tabs like this

```
{selectedTab === "EnNotification" ? (
        <EnNotification
          formData={formData}
          setFormData={setFormData}
        />
      ) : (
        <HiNotification
          formData={formData}
          setFormData={setFormData}
        />
      )}
```

when I enter the data in one tab suppose in EnNotification tab the state updates but when I tried to switch the tab it give me the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'notificationTitle')
```

My input component looks like:

```
 <Input
          value={formData.en.notificationSubTitle || ""}
          placeholder="Notification Sub Title"
          onChange={(event) => {
            const tempval = event.target.value;
            setFormData((data) => ({
              en: { ...data.en, notificationSubTitle: tempval },
            }));
          }}
        />
```

I think the problem is from only one component I'm able to update the state, but I want it should be updated from both.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are updating the formData state, before replacing the object *en*, you should also copy the rest of the value from the current state. Try this instead:

```
setFormData((data) => ({
 ...data,
 en: { ...data.en, notificationSubTitle: tempval },
}));
```